# AWS EC2 instance keeps failing "Instance reachability failed" after every 24 hours or less

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 t2.micro Linux instance where I am running only one service keeps failing the 1 out of 2 checks "Instance reachability check". To solve it I either reboot or start and stop the instance which solves the instance reachability problem for a limited time.

But this solutions only last for less than a day, after around 18~22 hours I see again my instance reachability check starts failing. In this system log I only see a problem with boot, the message says:

```
32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m.
```

After this, the only solution I am left is with start and stop the instance. I am unable to reach AWS support as I have a Basic plan. Checking here if anyone can help me sort out this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There are two checks, `System status checks` and `Instance status checks`. Which one is failing? Also get the `system logs` and paste in your question.

Comment: I found that elastic search running on my t2 micro instace makes the instance fail after few hours.